# How do I fix "Unknown column in 'field list'"

Tags: php, mysql, field, fieldlist

I am currently doing a school project which involves creating a website for users to input events. But I am currently facing this problem of:

> Cannot insert event title
> Error Code:
> Unknown column 'event_title' in 'field list' ]

this is my coding:

```
<?php  

$e_title = $_POST['title'];
$e_venue = $_POST['venue'];
$e_date1 = $_POST['date1'];
$e_date2 = $_POST['date2'];
$e_time1 = $_POST['time1'];
$e_time2 = $_POST['time2'];
$e_remarks = $_POST['remarks'];
$e_blurbs = $_POST['blurbs'];
$e_organiser = $_POST['organiser'];

if ($e_title=='') {
exit ("Event Field is empty. Click to <a href=addevent.php> Go Back</a>");
}

$conn = @mysql_connect ('localhost', 'root','');
if (!$conn) die ("<p>No MYSQL Connection</p>");
$conn = mysql_select_db('events');
if (!$conn) die("<p>Cannot select database</p>");

$sql = "INSERT into `event` (event_title, event_venue, event_date1, event_date2, event_time1,
event_time2, event_remarks, event_blurbs, event_organiser) VALUES ( '$e_title', '$e_venue', '$e_date1', '$e_date2', '$e_time1','$e_time2', '$e_remarks', '$e_blurbs', '$e_organiser')"; 


$result = @mysql_query ($sql);

if(!$result){
exit( "<p>Cannot insert event title</p>  Error Code: <p>". mysql_error()."</p>");
}
else {
echo "event saved successfully!";
}

?>
```

this is my coding in `phpmyadmin` database "events" ...I'm currently using `XAMPP`

```sql
CREATE TABLE EVENT(
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    title TEXT,
    venue TEXT,
    date1 DATE NOT NULL
    date2 DATE NOT NULL
    time1 TIME 
    time2 TIME
    remarks TEXT,
    blurbs TEXT,
    organiser TEXT
)
```

Comment: change `event_title` to `title` inside your query ( same goes for other fields ).

Answer (score 1):

The columns in your table do not start with `event_` whereas the columns in your `INSERT` list do. Remove the `event_` from all columns like this

```
$sql = "INSERT into `event` (title, venue, date1, date2, time1,
time2, remarks, blurbs, organiser) VALUES ( '$e_title', '$e_venue', '$e_date1', '$e_date2', '$e_time1','$e_time2', '$e_remarks', '$e_blurbs', '$e_organiser')";
```

You should consider using `mysql_*` functions, these will be removed in future versions. Also sanitize the data passed from a form before using in any database operation to **avoid SQL injection attacks**

Answer (score 1):

Remove `event_from` the column names as your database table columns is mismatches with the column name you provided with the query.
So use :

```sql
$sql = "INSERT into `event` (title,venue,date1,date2,time1,time2,remarks,blurbs,organiser)
  VALUES ('$e_title','$e_venue','$e_date1','$e_date2','$e_time1','$e_time2','$e_remarks','$e_blurbs','$e_organiser');"
```

It should work

Answer (score 0):

The DB query should be changed as this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE EVENT(
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    event_title TEXT,
    event_venue TEXT,
    event_date1 DATE NOT NULL
    event_date2 DATE NOT NULL
    event_time1 TIME 
    event_time2 TIME
    event_remarks TEXT,
    event_blurbs TEXT,
    event_organiser TEXT
);
```

Or you can try changing the PHP script as

```
$sql = "INSERT into `event` (title, venue, date1, date2, time1,
time2, remarks, blurbs, organiser) VALUES ( '$e_title', '$e_venue', '$e_date1', '$e_date2', '$e_time1','$e_time2', '$e_remarks', '$e_blurbs', '$e_organiser')";
```

Don't do both changes. The error is because the name of attributes in the table must be the same as PHP SQL passing parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the `DB QUERY` to

```sql
CREATE TABLE EVENT(
  id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  event_title TEXT,
  event_venue TEXT,
  event_date1 DATE NOT NULL
  event_date2 DATE NOT NULL
  event_time1 TIME 
  event_time2 TIME
  event_remarks TEXT,
  event_blurbs TEXT,
  event_organiser TEXT
)
```